# Exposed filters submit with AJAX not working - regular submit instead

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I created and customized exposed forms. When I change some values I change exposed filters widgets accordingly. Then I call submit with JavaScript, but my form is send with regular submit not like I checked on Views Advanced Settings form to use AJAX. What could be wrong with that? Pagination also change current URL.

-- edit --
When I click on item connected with exposed filter I execute this code:

```
$('#category-product-finder .frame a').each(function() {
    var $a = $(this);
    var $exposed_filter = $('#views-exposed-form-product-finder-page');
    $a.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $exposed_filter.find('#edit-product-category').val($a.attr('rel'));
        $('#views-exposed-form-product-finder-page').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

And this make my form to submit without using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you edit the templating of view? As AJAX views use the default ID's to attach itself to the form and view itself. If you've altered / removed these ID's, it would explain why the form submits in a regular way.

A few lines of the selectors in ajax_views.js to get you on the right path:

```
var selector = '.view-dom-id-' + settings.view_dom_id;

...

// Add the ajax to exposed forms.
this.$exposed_form = $('form#views-exposed-form-'+ settings.view_name.replace(/_/g, '-') + '-' + settings.view_display_id.replace(/_/g, '-'));
this.$exposed_form.once(jQuery.proxy(this.attachExposedFormAjax, this));
```

Comment: This helped me. I had removed the attribute classes from my wrapper div. Thanks a ton! Saved me a lot of banging my head against the table. +1

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Ambidex idea is the key. My problem was that I didn't have printer classess within views-view--XXXX.tpl.php. After this everything works OK and there is something like "view-dom-id-82374yrcnuerhnw875yt3o8743y" (first line of Ambidex code) class added, which is probably needed by AJAX calls.

Comment: What do you mean by printer classes (have same problem). I already have the view-dom-id-xxxxx class on my view which needs to be filtered. Still doesn't even work without any custom TPLs ?

Comment: There should be printeD classes. 
`<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
    <?php echo $exposed; ?>
    <?php
    if ($rows): ?>
    <ul class="products">
    <?php echo $rows; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>`
First I missed print $classess which is required by Drupal;
I created views with exposed filters - then hide it with CSS and display another view (nice looking) to manage exposed filters.